# My 2009 kia rio gives a gunshot sound when accelerating

Tags: kia, rio

My kia rio 2009 suddenly start bring this gunshot sound when accelerating . It misses fire hence causing the car to move very slowly..
My mechanic has changed both the fuel pump and the fuel filter and yet the problem won't stop.please what other step should I take.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I suggest you try another mechanic, I don't believe that the fuel filter or the fuel pump would be the root cause of a misfire. That is more likely to be due to a faulty crank position sensor or fuel metering issue.

Answer (score 1):

Misfire is usually due to a failure in the ignition system, it would be best to start there. The fuel system (fuel pump and filter would be the last place I would look).

Spark plugs are an obvious candidate.  Also, do you have a check engine light on?  Can you read the OBD codes, they can tell you if a sensor has failed and remove the guesswork.